# Exception when starting ChromeDriver() on MAC

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Team,

Cleaning up one of my eclipse projects and I can't seem to get the ChromeDrive() to return a webDriver.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/commons/exec/Executor
```

I have the latest Selenium jar files  2.47.1
HTTPClient jar 4.5.2
HTTPCore jar 4.4.4

Question:

Do I know need to set a system variable to point to the chrome app?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/Google Chrome.app");
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The class causing the problem is

```
org/apache/commons/exec/Executor
```

So, make sure that in your classpath is included the `commons-exec-1.3.jar` Jar file.

You cand get it from  [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22commons-exec%22)

Answer (score 0):

Setup instructions for Chrome WebDriver [are here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started). See this bit in particular:

> ChromeDriver is a **separate executable** that WebDriver uses to control
>   Chrome. It is maintained by the Chromium team with help from WebDriver
>   contributors. If you are unfamiliar with WebDriver, you should check
>   out their own Getting Started page.

So you need to [download ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), add its location to your `PATH` environment variable. Only then can you can do:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<my ChromeDriver path>");
```

In other words, you don't control Chrome directly, ChromeDriver takes care of all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you or all the help. My project was old, I just created a Maven project and updated everything, and all works.  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You must have changed `webdriver.chrome.driver` though, as setting it to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` won't work.

Comment: Team,  Chrome and Firefox are working well on my MAC OSX  but I can't create a Safari webDriver. I get the following error:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFactory  Here is my code:  SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
   options.setUseCleanSession(true); //if you wish safari to forget session everytime
  return (driver = new SafariDriver(options));